# won't tell VS allow

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Are these three sentences the same meaning?
If not, what the differences?

> 1. His parents always say to him, "Do not stay out late."
> 2. His parents won't allow him to stay out late.
> 3. His parents won't tell him to stay out late.

I really appreciate your reply.

Comment: Could you narrow down what you need? I can't see how say vs. allow vs. tell could have the same meaning as the are different verbs. At least let us know how you understand each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that "him" is the parents' son and that you are trying to detail a situation of continued prohibition. I think that this is what you are getting at. Then  1. and 2. convey the same meaning: The parents prohibit the son from "staying out late".

The difference is that in 1. can mean that the son asks each time he wants to stay out late, and each time his parents so no. 2. can mean that the parents told him *once* and that is the rule. No questions asked.

Number 3. does not have this meaning. It sounds like you are saying that the parents do not *command* the son to stay out late. I think what you mean to say is

> His parents won't tell him that he can stay out late.

This has the same meaning as the other two. But it could also be interpreted as they allow him to stay out, but they simply *don't say it*. Maybe they give hints, or don't punish him  and ignore it if or when he stays out late.

Comment: I disagree that 1 implies "the son probably asks each time he wants to stay out late". For example, Son: "I'm heading out now!" Parents: "Do not stay out late!" I also disagree that 2 implies "the parents told him once and that is the rule". For example: Bob always asks to go to the movies with his friends but his parents won't allow him to stay out late.

Comment: Ummm, I shouldn't have said probably. I don't see how your example disagrees with my interpretation of 2.